# Existence of game/programming environment hybrids for Android

Tags: user-expectation

I was wondering whether people would appreciate a game/programming hybrid where there were people that interacted, but an interface was presented to program what a person could say and do, and then you could even share the code.

Each garden could present different characters and algorithms for the people to talk, do, and interact (and you could code specifically to any given garden).

Each time you code a character, you can run the simulation.

Do any such game/programmer hybrids exist in the Google Play store?

Please migrate my post to software recommendations if more appropriate there.

Thanks.

Comment: Meta comment: i never made good experiences with asking whether people would appreciate this or that — there is no cost to saying yes, and people are extremely bad at predicting what they need or want, especially in the future and without seeing it.